# como configurar rotas no laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

estou estudando mais por conta própria o Laravel, e sim ja olhei a documentação dele sobre rotas e não consigo fazer funcionar aqui.

fiz um pequeno teste:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('teste', function() {
    return view('teste');
});
```

e criei o arquivo `teste.blade.php` na pasta `resources/views/teste.blade.php`
esta junto com o arquivo `welcome.blade.php`, onde ela funciona sem problemas, mas quando coloco no browser `dev.project/teste` ele não acha o arquivo.
mas se colocar `dev.project/` ele abre o arquivo welcome.

alguém pode me dizer se falta alguma configuração, ou talvez eu tenha que criar um arquivo controller pra rodar?

Comment: você executou por algum servidor ou foi o do próprio PHP?

Comment: O correto é você criar um arquivo controller e de lá você chamar a view. O arquivo routes.php deve ser apenas para fazer essa transferência de rotas para controller e não para executar funções ou chamar views..

Answer (score 1):

Como citado nos comentários, o correto é você criar um Controller e lá você prepara os dados para enviar para a view. Exemplo:

**Rota:**

```
Route::get('/teste', ['as'=>'teste.index', 'uses'=> 'TesteController@index']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){
    return view('teste.index');
}
```